# setting a flag for score change in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with exam scores for different weeks. I wanted to create an extra column with the score difference, like if score decreased by 0-5 then 1, 5-9 then 2, 10+ then 3 and if score increases then 4. Here is the sample data that I have with me in the table.

```
--DROP TABLE #Scores
CREATE TABLE #Scores (
    NAME varchar(10),
    Grade varchar(10),
    Subject varchar(25),
    Exam_Date datetime,
    Score int
)

INSERT INTO #Scores
    VALUES ('Sam', 'XI', 'Maths', '2016-08-01 15:47:29.533', 38), 
           ('Sam', 'XI', 'Maths', '2016-07-25 15:47:29.533', 50), 
           ('Mike', 'XI', 'Maths', '2016-08-01 15:47:29.533', 50), 
           ('Mike', 'XI', 'Maths', '2016-07-25 15:47:29.533', 45)

SELECT * FROM #Scores
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `lag()` and `case`:

```
select s.*,
       (case when score - prev_score < 0 then 4
             when score - prev_score <= 5 then 1
             when score - prev_score <= 9 then 2
             else 3
        end) as score_diff
from (select s.*,
             lag(score) over (partition by name, subject order by exam_date) as prev_score
      from #scores s
     ) s;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for the reply, but this is not giving me the data i am looking for score - prev_score this is not the right logic i guess, because if   score is less the previous score we are getting neagative value and the logic is considering it as less than zero. example (current scor (30)-previous score(50)) insted of giving the flag 3 it is giving me the 4.

Comment: @user3311323 . . . That is how your question is phrased.  Perhaps you really want to do the subtraction in the other order, however.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff, I change the code a little bit. The logic is right, just change the math a little.

```
select s.*,
       (case when score - prev_score > 0 then 4
             when score - prev_score between -5 and 0 then 1
             when score - prev_score between -9 and -5 then 2
             else 3
        end) as score_diff
from (select s.*,
             lag(score) over (partition by name, subject order by exam_date) as prev_score
      from #scores s
     ) s;
```

Result is captured and shown below:

[image]

Comment: The `case` conditions are always searched in order in case you weren't sure about that. I believe that's why you had to rearrange it.

Comment: @shawnt00 Sorry I dont get it. Why I have to rearrange it. Yes the case conditions are always searched in order, but since there is no duplicate in between, that is ok.

Comment: Nevermind. I was just glancing at Gordon's answer. I thought his is the one that had this problem but I see it was actually just the difference in sign after the subtraction.

Comment: Actually I thought you were posting the answer to your own question. I probably should have paid more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a further step of normalization. Keep the scores in a separate table. Relate the student to the scores table.

You have to decide how you are going to reference the previous score to compare to the current. If you create an additional field to either store the change from last score then you can have a calculated field that shows the current score, or, store the previous score in a field along side the new score, then have a calculated field show the change between the two.

Comment: i am happy to add few extra columns if needed.

Comment: Additional columns are fine, however, if you can derive at the value of the column from a calculation, do that first if all things are equal. In other words, if you know the previous and new score, then you should calculate the difference. Reason being, if you update a score field, you also have to remember to update the change field. If it's calculated, no need to update that as well. Better chance your data will stay correct.